# Proving that the circumcenter is the centroid

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, triangles

Given a triangle and its centroid, we know that the 3 line segments between the centroid and each of the vertices of the triangle divide the triangle into three smaller triangles. Prove that the circumcenter of the original triangle is the centroid of the triangle formed by the circumcenters of the smaller triangles.

Using vectors seems like a decent idea, but any other suggestions would be great.